# HTML5 player - without fallback

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm looking for an HTML5 audio/video player. I need to have the same graphic rendering (each browser has its own) and same controllers in every browser (eg, Firefox has only the button to turn off/on the volume, but doesn't allow you to set an intermediate value, as happens for example with Chrome).

On internet there are many software, also very valid, but all of these propose a fallback player, often in flash. But I don't want a fallback player and I can not find anything that will work for my case!

I could modify any of these and remove fallback files and code, but I was wondering if you know of something that already exists and that shows a warning message to the user if the browser doesn't support HTML5 or if the media type is not supported.

Thank you.

Comment: AFIK you can add the missing buttons per JavaScript the API should be the same on all browsers.

Comment: Yes, I've already done. I have already made a nice plugin for jquery, complete with everything. Let's say that it replaces the full native player. But there is a big problem: with the video in full screen mode, however the native player is used.

It requires too much work and then should be updated in the future, while I would be interested to know if there is already a comprehensive product that does it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:
http://www.leanbackplayer.com

Allows you to choose freely which fallback use, including none or a string.

It works well, nice.